# Как создать обработчик для динамического визуального компонента?

Tags: c++, c++builder

Например, создал я кнопку в программе и хочу чтоб при её нажатии что либо происходило.

```
TTabItem *TabItem13;
...

TabItem13 = new TTabItem(TabControl4);
TabItem13->Parent = TabControl4;
TabItem13->Text = "add new account";
```

Вот созданый обьект.

Comment: Что вам мешает присвоить OnClick? OnMouseDown?

Comment: почему то оно не работает.

Comment: Покажите на примере. У вас нету в приведённом вопросе строки `TabItem13->OnClick=Handler_Proc`